# Chrome error after hitting back to safety on the security page

Tags: google-chrome, networking, custom-errors

So after i hit back when seeing the message on chrome saying that my connection isnt secure on a HTTPS
now i can not access this page on my network and can only access it on my vps... is there any way I can fix this i searched all over the web and im so blown cause now i can't access my own webpage..

PS: I have tried accessing the page on another computer on the same network and i get the same error message of ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT when ever i try to go to the page, and yes i have tryed connecting on another router and the page loads fine and is a live copy of the page. please help me

```
Your connection is not private

Attackers might be trying to steal your information from xxxxx.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards).

Back to safety Hide advanced
This server could not prove that it is (website).com; its security certificate is from server1.(website).com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

Proceed to (website).com (unsafe)

NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

Comment: As you are doing https, you might need a valid ssl certificate for this or may be for trial purpose you can add exceptions in the browser or adding  a self sign certificate into your trusted root store.

Comment: Its not woring on the real website either, the regular http

Comment: it won't warn on http. But when you are trying to access the page over secure protocol and if you don''t have the certificate its trying to tell the end user that its not safe even if you use https.